# Tomcat Parallel Deployment - Go to older version

Tags: java, tomcat, server

Let's say that I have two deployments running on my `Tomcat`:

- myApp##1.war
- myApp##2.war

So fresh sessions will go to the 2nd app; but is there a way to get into the 1st app?

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Currently the capability you're asking for is not implemented in parallel deployment: the only way to access the old version of your application is to provide a valid session ID (like a cookie) for the older version, otherwise ALL expired sessions/new sessions will be directed to the newer version.

Comment: So I would login in my old version before deploy the new war, and so then I'll be logged in the older app. That is what you mean?

Comment: As long as you have a valid session for the older version, Tomcat will redirect your request correctly. As soon as your session expires you will ALWAYS get redirected to the new version... no workaround on this.